# Testing current value of a property in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

How to test that in Jasmine:

```
buffer: number[] = [];

initP(): void {
    if (this.buffer.length) {
      this.buffer = [];
    }
    this.buffer = this.buffer.concat([27, 64]);
  }
```

I tried to pass current value like that:

```
it('should initialise it', () => {
    spyOn(pService, 'initP');
    pService.initP();
    expect(buffer).toBe([27, 64]);
    expect(pService.initP).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Problem is that I'm getting that error:

**Expected [  ] to be [ 27, 64 ]**.

I'm injecting my service in beforeEach block like that:

```
let pService;
let buffer: number[];

beforeEach(inject([PService], _pService => {
    pService = _pService;
    buffer = _pService.buffer;
  }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.and.callThrough();` so that it still calls the original function. Otherwise it won't hit the original implementation of `initP`.

```
spyOn(pService, 'initP').and.callThrough();
```

Comment: Yes, I can see the progress now. But still getting an error: Expected [ 27, 64 ] to be [ 27, 64 ]. The value seems to be the same but it is not working for toBe(). Shall I use toEqual()?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `toEqual`. `toBe` checks that they are exactly the same object reference

Comment: Ah, so it is always boolean for toBe()... Thx!